# Sort a data.frame with columns of another data.frame

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have the folowing data.frames:

```
d1 <- data.frame(A=c(-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1), B=c(-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1), Y=c(2,3,4,5,8,9,10,11))
d2 <- data.frame(A=c(1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1), B=c(-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1))
```

I would like to add the column Y to the d2 data.frame. I've tried using `merge` function, but then I duplicate the number of rows of the data.frame.

I've also tried to use the functions `order` and `match` to order the first data.frame by the columns of the second one:

```
d1[order(match(
  paste(d1$A,d1$B),
  paste(d2df$A,d2df$B))
),]
```

But it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: is your goal to sort, or merely add Y to d2?

Comment: Please add expected output. Row `-1 -1` has value of `2` and `8` for column `Y`, how do you choose? Does d1 and d2 have the same number of rows?

Comment: I want to keep both rows. And yes, d1 and d2 have the same number of rows.

Comment: quite unsure on what your expected output is. take a look at the mutating joins as part of dplyr library https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: So you want to order d1 so that its columns appear in the same order as they are in d2? After this you wish to add Y from d2 to d1?

Comment: This is exactly what I want Olli J.

Comment: I think your expected output is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this would give you the results you're after:

```
# Sort d1 and d2 with columns A and B
d1 <- d1[order(d1$A,d1$B),]
d2 <- d2[order(d2$A,d2$B),]

# Copy Y from d1 to d2
d2$Y <- d1$Y

# Restore original order in d1 and d2
d1 <- d1[order(rownames(d1)),]
d2 <- d2[order(rownames(d2)),]

d2$Y
#[1]  4  5  3  2 11  9 10  8
```

Answer (score 0):

In case `d1` and `d2` have different number of rows:

```
chosen <- numeric(length = nrow(d1))
choices <- paste(d1$A, d1$B)

for(i in seq(nrow(d1))){
  chosen[i] <- match(paste(d2$A[i], d2$B[i]), choices)
  choices[chosen] <- 0
  }

d2$Y <- d1[chosen, "Y"]
d2$Y
#[1]  4  5  3  2 11  9 10  8
```